# Julia - Substitute for readandwrite()

Tags: pipe, julia, stdin

I am trying to open and write to an external application in Julia. From my research, I have found that there used to a function called readandwrite() that would do this task easily. However, it appears that that function was deprecated in an earlier release.

I have tried using the pipeline() command and run() to little success. I also tried opening it and writing to it with write() but write does not take an IOstream. I have been [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/document-process-interaction-with-stdin-stout-stderr/7251/2) and tried out the code snippets, but none seem to work. Others I do not know where to put the path of the file.

```
p=open(pipeline(`./$xPath`; stderr=Pipe()), "r") 
(Pipe(RawFD(-1) closed => RawFD(20) open, 0 bytes waiting), Process(`./$xPath`, ProcessExited(0)))
```

Where xPath is a string containing the path to the file ("xfoil.exe")
This code returns an unknown error and that it could not spawn the executable file. 
Any help would be appreciated as I have hit a wall with opening this file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running on Julia 0.7 you get this warning:

```
julia> readandwrite(`ls`)
[ Warning: `readandwrite(::Cmd)` is deprecated in favor of `open(::Cmd, "r+").
[ You may read/write the returned process object for access to stdio.
```

So the replacement is:

```
p = open(`ls`, "r+")
```

and then use `read` and  `write` on `p`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, when run this is fails to spawn the program. Even trying this on a simple text document fails. See the error message here: https://pastebin.com/s7ZqGNNk

Comment: Can you run the backticked program without the pipes? The error you list in pastebin looks as if the program run in backticks is the one generating an error.

Comment: Using run(`program`) does generate the same error. However, the program is in file directory. run(`test.txt`) also generates the same error so the program is not at fault.

Comment: What do you think run( test.txt ) should actually do?

Comment: I must have it wrong. I assumed that run would open its input.